# Internet Explorer not showing PHP files while directory browsing. Help me

Tags: php, internet-explorer, installation, xampp

I am sure i created a php file into a folder named web in htdocs folder. But while directory browsing it shows only html, css files inside that folder. But the php files are not shown. Help me

Comment: Are you sure it's **Internet** Explorer, not **Windows** Explorer? If it's Windows Explorer/File Manager, you might be better asking this question on either Serverfault or Superuser.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the directory listing created by [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html) it could be an [IndexIgnore](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore) directive that excludes .php files from the listing. But the [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) default configuration does not include such a directive.